# How to make amcharts 5 flight from source to destination only

Tags: javascript, amcharts5

I have a requirement for the amcharts 5 map to show plane fly from the source (Paris) to the destination (LA) only and not turn around and fly back as it does for the demo map from amcharts.

Does anyone know how this would be achieved or should I be using another animation?

```
// Create root element
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

// Set themes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

// Create the map chart
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/map-chart/
var chart = root.container.children.push(am5map.MapChart.new(root, {
  panX: "rotateX",
  panY: "translateY",
  projection: am5map.geoMercator(),
  homeGeoPoint: { latitude: 2, longitude: 2 }
}));

var cont = chart.children.push(am5.Container.new(root, {
  layout: root.horizontalLayout,
  x: 20,
  y: 40
}));

// Create series for background fill
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/map-chart/map-polygon-series/#Background_polygon
var backgroundSeries = chart.series.push(am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {}));
backgroundSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
  fill: root.interfaceColors.get("alternativeBackground"),
  fillOpacity: 0,
  strokeOpacity: 0
});

// Add background polygon
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/map-chart/map-polygon-series/#Background_polygon
backgroundSeries.data.push({
  geometry: am5map.getGeoRectangle(90, 180, -90, -180)
});

// Create main polygon series for countries
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/map-chart/map-polygon-series/
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {
  geoJSON: am5geodata_worldLow
}));

// Create line series for trajectory lines
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/map-chart/map-line-series/
var lineSeries = chart.series.push(am5map.MapLineSeries.new(root, {}));
lineSeries.mapLines.template.setAll({
  stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("alternativeBackground"),
  strokeOpacity: 0.3
});

// Create point series for markers
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/map-chart/map-point-series/
var pointSeries = chart.series.push(am5map.MapPointSeries.new(root, {}));

pointSeries.bullets.push(function() {
  var circle = am5.Circle.new(root, {
    radius: 7,
    cursorOverStyle: "pointer",
    tooltipY: 0,
    fill: am5.color(0xffba00),
    stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("background"),
    strokeWidth: 2,
    draggable: false
  });

  return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
    sprite: circle
  });
});

var paris = addCity({ latitude: 48.8567, longitude: 2.351 }, "Paris");
var la = addCity({ latitude: 34.3, longitude: -118.15 }, "Los Angeles");

var lineDataItem = lineSeries.pushDataItem({
  pointsToConnect: [paris, la]
});

var plane = am5.Graphics.new(root, {
  svgPath:
    "m2,106h28l24,30h72l-44,-133h35l80,132h98c21,0 21,34 0,34l-98,0 -80,134h-35l43,-133h-71l-24,30h-28l15,-47",
  scale: 0.06,
  centerY: am5.p50,
  centerX: am5.p50,
  fill: am5.color(0x000000)
});

planeSeries.bullets.push(function() {
  var container = am5.Container.new(root, {});
  container.children.push(plane);
  return am5.Bullet.new(root, { sprite: container });
});

var planeDataItem = planeSeries.pushDataItem({
  lineDataItem: lineDataItem,
  positionOnLine: 0,
  autoRotate: true
});

planeDataItem.animate({
  key: "positionOnLine",
  to: 1,
  duration: 10000,
  loops: Infinity,
  easing: am5.ease.yoyo(am5.ease.linear)
});

planeDataItem.on("positionOnLine", function(value) {
  if (value >= 0.99) {
    plane.set("rotation", 180);
  } else if (value <= 0.01) {
    plane.set("rotation", 0);
  }
});

function addCity(coords, title) {
  return pointSeries.pushDataItem({
    latitude: coords.latitude,
    longitude: coords.longitude
  });
}

// Make stuff animate on load
chart.appear(1000, 100);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/codeblazor/9nqpugf0/27/

Answer (score 0):

There were a few items to fix here.

1. The delay is introduced by using the delay attribute in the animate
   function. The delay happens before the animation starts, thus
   serving as the pause at the end of each animation cycle.
2. The constant pauseDuration represents the time the plane will pause
   before starting the animation again. This delay is applied before
   each cycle of animation due to the loops: Infinity parameter, which
   causes the animation to repeat indefinitely.
3. To prevent the plane from flickering at the destination; only rotate
   the plane at the beginning of the path in the planeDataItem.on("positionOnLine", function.

```js
// Create a new constant to store the animation duration (in ms)
const animationDuration = 10000; // 10 seconds for plane travel
const pauseDuration = 1000; // 1 second pause at the end

planeDataItem.animate({
  key: "positionOnLine",
  to: 1,
  duration: animationDuration,
  easing: am5.ease.linear,
  delay: pauseDuration, // delay added before animation starts, which serves as pause at the end of each animation cycle
  loops: Infinity
});

planeDataItem.on("positionOnLine", function(value) {
  if (value <= 0.01) {
    plane.set("rotation", 0);
  }
});

// ...
```

Here's the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Devlins/2j5309a6/